# force close error on this activity when using progress dialog

Tags: android, webview, progressdialog

what is issue in this code it says force close?
error occurred when using progress dialog

```
ourBrow = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);
ourBrow.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
ourBrow.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
ourBrow.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Moile_gole.this, "",
                    "Loading. Please wait...", true);
        ourBrow.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        dialog.dismiss();
            // HIDE PROGRESS DIALOG LOADING IT HAS FINISHED
        }

    });

    ourBrow.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Logcat:

```
10-03 20:43:59.440: D/AndroidRuntime(304): Shutting down VM 10-03 20:43:59.440: W/dalvikvm(304):
threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800) 10-03 20:43:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(304): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
10-03 20:43:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(304): java.lang.NullPointerException 
10-03 20:43:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(304): at com.mobile.specification.Moile_Specification$2.onProgressChanged(Moile_Specifica‌​tion.java:68) 
10-03 20:43:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(304): at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:358)
10-03 20:43:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(304): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
10-03 20:43:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(304): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-03 20:43:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(304): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 
10-03 20:43:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(304): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
10-03 20:43:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(304): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 
10-03 20:43:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(304): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868) 
10-03 20:43:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(304): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 
10-03 20:43:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(304): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please post your logcat details also and btw it's http://www.google.com :)

Comment: i changed url any url shows error 
here is logcat

Comment: sorry i am unable to paste logcat stackoverflow shows error

Comment: 10-03 20:43:59.440: D/AndroidRuntime(304): Shutting down VM
10-03 20:43:59.440: W/dalvikvm(304): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
10-03 20:43:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(304): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-03 20:43:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(304): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-03 20:43:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at com.mobile.specification.Moile_Specification$2.onProgressChanged(Moile_Specification.java:68)
10-03 20:43:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:358)

Comment: 10-03 20:43:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-03 20:43:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-03 20:43:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-03 20:43:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-03 20:43:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

Comment: 10-03 20:43:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-03 20:43:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-03 20:43:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: i saw your logcat. You are getting a Null Pointer Exception. Check the line number where you're getting it and debug your app. It's better you add the logcat in your question rather than in the comment.

Comment: the error mentioned in the stack at com.mobile.specification.Moile_Specification$2.onProgressChanged(Moile_Specifica‌​tion.java:68) has nothing to code with code posted in your question!!

Comment: M NEWBEE IN DEVELOPMENT N DONT KNOW ABT DEBUG MODE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force Close Error is occurred due to NullPointerException caused by dialog. shouldOverrideUrlLoading() method is called only when links inside a WebView are clicked and not called when you try to load webpage via webview.loadUrl(url). So here your dialog is not initialized and causing the NullPointerException.

I suggest you to use webchromeclient and ProgressBar(pb) to show the webpage loading Progress as below sample.

```
wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

         public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) 
         {

             pb.setProgress(progress);
             if(progress==100)
                 pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          }


    });
```

Comment: unable to find any solution plz can u modify my code u given me code but i need progressdialog not progressbar

Comment: sorry for this question i was not declared this in layout so that this problem occurred.